# How to capture PID of a background process

Tags: bash, unix, pid

I am a bit confused on how PID's are allocated by BASH shell so I need your help to understand this using a problem which I am trying to resolve here. I am calling a function in a shell script. This function runs another groovy script in background as seen below:

```
fn_list()
{
... ... ... 
groovy list_gn.gy -p $prop_file $@ &
echo "Extracting PID No :$!" >> $logpid
}
```

I am calling this function like this inside a loop:

```
for x in `cat $list | grep -v '#'`; do
fn_list &
echo "Extracting function PID No :$!" >> $logpid
done
```

Since I am running this function in background, and also the groovy which being run by this function runs in background (using &).

My question is that I am logging PID of the function and I am also logging PID of the groovy script which is being calling from inside of this function. Will the PID's for the function and the groovy which is being called from inside this function be different ? And is it a correct way to log the PIDs ?

I am need to understand it's behavior because I am planning to fork the function process 3 times. So want to be absolutely sure if that's a right approach.

Comment: Child processes run in their own separate shell. As long as you use `$!` you can get safely their id's and to clarify, the two id's in your logic will be different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually pid are not allocated by bash but by the operating system, when a process is forked it is assigned a new pid, calling `groovy .. &` from bash process creates a new child process groovy which parent in bash process.

a bash function call doesn't create a new pid because it is run in the same process the same for a builtin command.

However because of the `&` after the function call this creates a new bash process (subshell), maybe one of the two `&` is not needed.

If you are interessed by the result of these processes you may need to wait for their execution this is what `wait` builtin does, a parallel execution could look to.

```
pids=()
for ... ; do
    groovy ... &
    pids+=( "$!" )
done

exit_codes=()
for pid in "${pid[@]}"; do
    wait "$pid"
    exit_codes+=( "$?" )
done
```

Comment: Thank you @Nahuel... Yes you are right, there is no need of calling the function in background. I am only forking the groovy script now. The wait "$pid" solved my problem. That's what I wanted to make sure. Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: you're welcome, don't hesitate to accept the answer if it resolves the issue

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul this looks elegant, any idea why when I try this code with `rsync` command instead of `groovy`, the pids array contains only a single pid regardless the number of executions?

Comment: @ChenA. thanks for your comment, it seems rsync forks itself, maybe following can be interesting https://serverfault.com/questions/460423/why-does-rsync-forks-itself-and-why-one-such-forked-process-is-almost-kinda-idl